# I don't know how to passing array variabel from jquery to other php page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

here is my code from o2m.php
im using datatable with checkbox from https://datatables.net/extensions/select/examples/initialisation/checkbox.html

what i try to do is passing the data from variable tmpData[i] to other php page.
So when i check multiple data, the data get inside tmpData[i] and pass to other page so other page can use that variable with the data from before.

```
<script>
  var table;
$(document).ready(function() {
  table = $('#example').DataTable({
    columnDefs: [{
      orderable: false,
      className: 'select-checkbox',
      targets: 0
    }, {
      "targets": [2],
      "visible": false,
      "searchable": false
    }],
    select: {
      style: 'os',
      selector: 'td:first-child'
    },
    order: [
      [1, 'asc']
    ]
  });
});


$('#btnSelectedRows').on('click', function() {

 tblData = table.rows('.selected').data();


  var tmpData =[];
  $.each(tblData, function( i,val) {
    tmpData[i] = tblData[i][3];

    alert(tmpData[i]);

  });
```

here is my ajax code but when i change page the output are Notice: Undefined index: info in C:\xampp\htdocs\skripsi\sendinto.php on line 6

```
 $.ajax({
        url: 'o2m.php',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
            info: JSON.stringify(tmpData)
        }
    }).done(function(data) {
        //Redirect to another page if you want...
        window.location.href = "sendinto.php";
    });
});


</script>
```

this is my code in **sendinto.php**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php 

session_start();
$data = json_decode($_POST['info']);
$_SESSION['info'] = $data; 
echo $data;
?>
```

Comment: You can pass data table array to ajax and add into session array and use this session any php page

Comment: @BhAvikGajjar i already make the ajax code but the output Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\skripsi\sendinto.php on line 4
Array 
what should i do?

Comment: @SherlinTjoa Post also your `sendinto.php`. Check my answer.

Comment: @SherlinTjoa pass json like it JSON.stringify(tmpData)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are posting the request to file named o2m.php, while you are accessing the variable 'info' in sendinto.php. This is the page/file which you have put in the redirection when post call is done.

It can never access 'info' variable.
You can only access the post variables in the file to which you are posting the request.

Answer (score 0):

this is my **o2m.php** code
i initialize **session_start()** in here

```
<?php include "include/config.php"; 
session_start();
$query= mysqli_query($connection, " SELECT * FROM data ") 
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.1/css/select.dataTables.min.css" href="">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.1/css/select.dataTables.min.css">
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>

    h1 {color: Black; font: 35px Josefin Sans-, sans-serif;}

  </style>


   <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="WebLSA.php">
          <img src="image/logo.png" width="35" height="50" alt="" >
        </a>

  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="o2o.php">One to One</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="o2m.php">One to Many</a></li>
    <!--   <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Plagiarism?</a></li> -->
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="h2use.php">How to use</a></li>
      <!-- <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a></li> -->
    </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<br>
<center><h1> ONE TO MANY COMPARISON </h1></center>
```

in here , when i click the button get selected rows after i check the box i hope it can pass the data from tmpdata to other page

```
 <button id="btnSelectedRows">
      Get Selected Rows
    </button>
<!--  <button id="btnSelectedRows"  ><center>Compare</center></button>
</head> -->
<form action="aksi.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <center>
    <br>
    <input type="file" id="file" name="files[]" multiple="multiple" accept="txt" />
      <br>
      <br>

  </center>


<body>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-2"></div>  
  <div class="col-sm-8"><center>
  <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>

      <th scope="col">Pilih</th>
      <th scope="col">No</th>
      <th scope="col">Kode</th>
      <th scope="col">Judul</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php if (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {?>
    <?php $nomor =1;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { ?>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><?php echo $nomor; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row["Kode"]?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row["Judul"]?></td>

    </tr>
   <?php $nomor++; } ?>
 <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
    <th scope="col">Pilih</th>
      <th scope="col">No</th>
      <th scope="col">Kode</th>
      <th scope="col">Judul</th>


            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
    <br>

    <!-- <button id="btnSelectedRows" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" name="upload" ><center>Compare</center></button> -->

    <br>
</div>
</center>
<div class="col-sm-2"></div> 
</form>
```

i use json decode in here but when i start the page the output is Undefined index: info

```
<?php  
$data = json_decode($_POST['info']);
$_SESSION['info'] = $data;
?>
</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"> </script>
 <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"> </script>
 <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.1/js/dataTables.select.min.js"> </script>
 <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"> </script>
```

in here where i configure the table,

```
 <script>
      var table;
    $(document).ready(function() {
      table = $('

#example').DataTable({
        columnDefs: [{
          orderable: false,
          className: 'select-checkbox',
          targets: 0
        }, {
          "targets": [2],
          "visible": false,
          "searchable": false
        }],
        select: {
          style: 'os',
          selector: 'td:first-child'
        },
        order: [
          [1, 'asc']
        ]
      });
    });
```

in here when i click the button it pass the value from tmpdata to **sendinto.php**

```
$('#btnSelectedRows').on('click', function() {

 tblData = table.rows('.selected').data();

  var tmpData =[];
  $.each(tblData, function( i,val) {
    tmpData[i] = tblData[i][3];

    alert(tmpData[i]);

  });
```

and here is my ajax code

```
 $.ajax({
        url: 'sendinto.php',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
            info: JSON.stringify(tmpData)
        }
    }).done(function(data) {
        //Redirect to another page if you want...
        window.location.href = "sendinto.php";
    });
});   
</script>
</html>
```

this is my **sendinto.php** code

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php 

session_start(); 
$tes = $_SESSION['info']; 
echo $tes;
?>
```